# C# Mono String Format

Tags: c#, mono

I have a function called (`NumberFormat`) like PHP to format numbers but when I run that function on my server (linux centos) with Mono I always get an error.

```
static private string NumberFormat(BigInteger value)
    {
        string Format = null;
        if (value != 0)
        {
            Format = value.ToString("#,#",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        }
        else
        {
            Format = value.ToString();
        }

        return Format;
    }
```

Error: format '#,#' not implemented

Any solutions?

Comment: Look at the Mono documentation for `BigInteger` and use a supported format string?

Comment: Please next time come up with a better subject for your question.